# NextJS - Most Tailwind classes work... but not all

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have this weird case where classes like `w-1/2` work, but `w-1/3` wont, despite [being documented](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width).

This is my code:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 text-left text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase tracking-wider w-1/4">Invoice Number</th>
    <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 text-left text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase tracking-wider w-1/4">Customer</th>
    <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 text-left text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase tracking-wider w-1/4">Status</th>
    <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 text-left text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase tracking-wider w-1/4">Amount Due</th>
    <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 text-left text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase tracking-wider w-1/4">Actions</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

I know that they are not even being applied looking at the dev tools.

[image]

Checking the CSS file on `.next/static/css/` I can also see that the class is missing.

[image]

I am not sure what to do anymore. Here are the relevant config files.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "biller",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './src/context/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './src/utils/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './src/hooks/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

All the paths inside my `src` folder are covered, so that cannot be it.

**UPDATE**

I figured out part of it. Apparently it is due to the fact that I am not "hardcoding" the way that the class render on the JSX, but instead I am doing this:

```js
// "witdth" prop is optional. Can have values like "1/2", "1/3", "1/4", etc.
export const TH = ({ children, width }) => {
    const widthClass = width ? `w-${width}` : '';
    return (
        <th
            className={`px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 text-left text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase tracking-wider ${widthClass}`}
        >
            {children}
        </th>
    );
};
```

Apparently it will only be included if it is hardcoded. This sucks... is there a way to prevent this??

Comment: The error you are describing suggests that when you initially translated the Tailwind code to native CSS, it was done when using w-1/2. Later, when you modified it to w-1/3, you did not "re-translate" the code, causing the native CSS not to be updated based on the currently used classes. During Tailwind compilation, only those CSS classes are placed in your project that have been invoked at least once. Therefore, the w-1/3 that was not used in the initial translation is currently not present in the file.

Comment: If you look at the end, I have updated the post, because I found out now the reason why it is happening. It is due to me not hardcoding the class, but generating it dynamically. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Ah, after the update, I understand the problem better. Tailwind cannot determine exactly what you will use based on variables. You have two options. 1.) Instead of class names declared with variables, you explicitly write down the class names, and use a switch, for example, to insert the appropriate one into the classList. The other option is to use the safelist in the configuration, where you list the classes that you definitely want to include in your final native CSS code (regardless of whether you use them).

Comment: you can just "not use tailwind" for the values that you need to set dynamically, set css directly, `style={{width:width+"px"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Tailwind includes only the explicitly used and discoverable classes in your final CSS file. The reason behind this is to minimize the file size as much as possible.

Tailwind is unable to dynamically map classes that are not pre-defined in advance.

#### Solution

You can use a safelist to ensure that certain classes are always included in the final CSS code.

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
export default {
  safelist: [
    // can list them individually
    'w-1/2',
    'w-1/3',
    // or can create a more comprehensive rule as well
    {
      pattern: /^w-1\/\d+$/, // The regex written by @Wongjn can be perfect
    },
  ],
}
```

#### More information

- [Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) - TailwindCSS Docs
- [Using regular expressions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) - TailwindCSS Docs

Comment: I will mark this one as the accepted answer, as it explains why the class is not added, despite other answers contain even more alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider:

- [Safelisting all possible classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), forcing Tailwind to generate CSS rules for classes it has not found:

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    // …
    safelist: [
      'w-1/2',
      'w-1/3',
      'w-1/4',
    ]
    // …
  }
  ```

  Or

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    // …
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^w-1\/\d+$/ },
    ]
    // …
  }
  ```
- Refactor your code to use the `style` attribute:

  ```js
  // Have `width` be some valid CSS `width` value like `50%`, `33.3%`,
  // `25%` for `1/2`, `1/3`, `1/4` respectively.
  export const TH = ({ children, width }) => {
    return (
      <th
        className="…"
        style={{ width }}
      >
        {children}
      </th>
    );
  };
  ```

Comment: Wow, this sucks. Sucks HARD.

I guess I will go the safelist-route, but still... At this point I'd almost prefer to tell nextjs to include all the classes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent maybe can use `pattern: /^w-/`, so, you want to include every class starting with `w-`.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent I did specify in my answer – to tell nextjs to include all the classes, use `safelist` configuration.

Comment: What would be the "pattern" for "all classes"? My regexp is not really good :-/

Comment: This would not really be possible for v3 – there's an infinite amount of classes possible (due to the arbitrary features) and even without these, if you really wanted every single class possible, you would need to generate every possible combination of the variants, (like `dark:first:hover:focus:md:visited:last:only:…:m-1`) so there would be all the "base" classes plus all these permutations of variants and thus the total number of possible classes would be something like (70! + 1) (70! 70 factorial, equal to 1197857166996989179607278372168909873645893814254642585755536286462800958278984531968

Comment: 0000000000000000) × number of "base" classes (maths probably not correct here, but something like this). However, if you still wanted all but arbitrary classes , you'd do `safelist: [{ pattern: /^/, variants: ['sm', 'sm:md', 'sm:lg', …]}],`